# I want to start a project with webdriver and Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I start working with a project and want to start project with Selenium. Please suggest me how can i start write script in Eclipse with Java?

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: You better refer so many sites like seleniumeasy.com , guru99, toolsqa, softwaretestinghelp and many more.

Comment: i already work on selenium but stable project . now its a startup project so thats why i ask that how i start ....

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want JavaScript or Java? Because your title and body are different. 
If you want to do using Java then you know as you told that you are working. Just I want to give you one point for start up project that always use class/name/value/others use for Xpath, NEVER use ID. Because for every build the ID will changed.
If you want to set up your project using JavaScript then use WebDriverIO or WebDriverJS. You can google for details on that.

Comment: Java script....Thanks a lot for responce

Comment: If you found this (or any) answer helpful, please upvote it. If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!